# Using python code within Java (Jython) problems

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm trying to run some python code in real time (as my java code is running) but I keep running into the error below:

> SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '.' expecting NEWLINE", ('<>duplicatetesting.py', 11, 43, 'from Python import DuplicateDefectDetection.java\n'))

<> --> the text in here is the path to my python code
I've pretty much replicated what was outlined in [Accessing Jython from Java Without Using jythonc](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonMonthly/Articles/September2006/1).

**Code:**

> public interface DuplicateDefectDetection {
>       public String getRecallRate();
>       public void setBugsFile(String BugsFile);
>       public void setDuplicatesFile(String GD);
>       public void setNumTopics(int numTopics);
>       public void setCutOff(int cutOff);
>       public void setRecall(boolean recall);
>       public void runDuplicateTesting();
>       }

Comment: You cannot import directly a .java file. You need it compiled first and the resulting class filesomewhere accesible by python (eg.Java's classpath)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that import be:

```
from Python import DuplicateDefectDetection
```

I mean, without the `.java` part. Also, it has to be a compiled class, accessible from the classpath.

Comment: tried that, got: SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '3' expecting NAME", ('C:/Users/sakmal/Desktop/duplicatedetector/duplicatetesting.py', 14, 6, 'class 3D(DuplicateDefectDetection):\n'))

Comment: Try with an import declaration like this: `from fully.qualified.package import DuplicateDefectDetection`